# Pass variable in CURL URL

Tags: variables, url, curl

I have a simple bash script that uses REST API for one application. For that, I need to run this command:

```
curl --location --request DELETE 'https://example.com/jasperserver/rest_v2/resources/Reports/$var'
```

Please help me to figure out how exactly variable can be passed to URL. I could pass data using -d "$var", or username with password, but not URL.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use double quotes. It will do the variable expansion -

`curl --location --request DELETE "https://example.com/jasperserver/rest_v2/resources/Reports/$var"`

Single quote keeps it's content as it is (from GNU docs) -

> Enclosing characters in single quotes (‘'’) preserves the literal value of each character within the quotes. A single quote may not occur between single quotes, even when preceded by a backslash

So your url is interpreted as
`https://example.com/jasperserver/rest_v2/resources/Reports/$var`

Double quotes is similar to single quotes except it cares for special character like `$` (from GNU doc) -

> Enclosing characters in double quotes (‘"’) preserves the literal value of all characters within the quotes, with the exception of ‘$’, ‘`’, ‘\’, and, when history expansion is enabled, ‘!’